# Use framework that requires iOS 9 in app with deployment target iOS 8?

Tags: ios

For Android there's a tool called overrideLibrary that allows you to use libraries that require a higher target than your project. Is there a way to do the same for iOS?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/marking_api_availability_in_objective-c

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, the same behavior can be achieved by using `#available`,

```
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
    // use iOS 9 APIs
} else {
    // use less than iOS 9 APIs
}
```

Comment: Importing frameworks is not possible from code as far as I know. I've only imported them using Pods or by adding the file to the project.

Comment: I doubt if we can import Pods based on specific iOS version